# Automatic blank password attempts when fprintd is enabled in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad

I'm new to Ubuntu and would appreciate some insight on this problem. I followed this [GitHub](https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint/tree/vfs0090) tutorial on how to enable the fingerprint sensor for my specific device. It worked successfully the first time around with a success rate of 50/50 when trying to log in using my fingerprint. It would also only let me attempt my fingerprint once before it asked for a password. I thought maybe reinstalling all of it again would help. Well it only got worse when I tried reinstalling saying things were failing and etc. So I went down a huge rabbit hole on how to fix this. Finally I got it to work and it allowed me to enroll my fingerprint. I locked the account and once I tried logging in. It was making password attempts that are blank automatically like 7 times before it stops and allows me to put in my password. The fingerprint option wasn't even there either after it stops. I would like to get this working again.

I also tried running `sudo validity-sensors-tools.led-test` to verify if the scanner was working properly.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/0uSCHsD]